# Express and mysql. rows are undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js, regex, express

This is my code. I am writing API and I want to send information about products that client has input.

```
 const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('short'));
app.use(express.static('./public'));
// app.get('/', (req, res, next)=>{
//     res.send('Hello World');
// });
function getConnection(){
    return  mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password:'samsung793',
        database: 'demo2'

    })
}
app.get('/models/:id', (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log('Fetching id ' + req.params.id);
    const connection = getConnection();
    const queryStr = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=?'

    const modelId = req.params.id;

    connection.query( queryStr, [modelId], (err, rows, fields)=>{
        if (err){
            res.send('<h1>500 bad request</h1> Error! Sorry for error, we are working on it!');
            res.sendStatus(500);
           return;
            //throw err;
        }
        console.log('Ready');
        res.json(rows);
    })
    // res.end();
})
app.get('/:name', (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log('Fetching name ' + req.params.name);
    const connection = getConnection();
    const queryStr = `SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST(${req.params.name}, in natural language)`


    const modelName = req.params.name;

    connection.query( queryStr, [modelName], (err, rows, fields)=>{
        if (err){
            res.send('<h1>500 bad request</h1> <h3>Error!</h3> <h4>Sorry for error, we are working on it!</h4>');
            res.sendStatus(500);
           return;
            //throw err;
        }
        console.log('Ready');
        res.json(rows);
        console.log(rows);

    })
    // res.end();
})
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('server is listening on port 3000');
} )
```

when I log to console the rows, it is undefined. How can I fix it? What is the problem? 
Sorry for first post. I edit and add all code now. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You code is invalid. You are missing the end of the line `connection.query[...]`

Comment: Is your use of backticks (as opposed to inverted commas) correct?

Comment: It was a mistake when I copy it to here. Thank you

Comment: Backticks ? I think it is correct but I used different ways and problem is not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if any error occur while querying

```
app.get('/:name', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('Fetching name ' + req.params.name);
    const connection = getConnection();
    const queryStr = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST(?, in natural language mode)';
    const modelName = req.params.name;

     connection.query( queryStr, [modelName], (err, rows, fields)=>{
        console.log('Ready');
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        console.log(rows);
        res.json(rows);
    })
})
```

If you are using prepared statement, you do not need to pass `${req.params.name}`, just pass `?`

Comment: When I check error, it returns this.
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Comment: that means you did not posted complete code of `app.get('/:name'` route, please provide complete code, you are sending response more than once

Comment: Ok, I will edit the code and post complate code now.

Comment: After `res.send()`, response stream will be ended, check answer how to send response with status code, problem is inside `if(err)`

Comment: and also either use `${req.params.name}` in backticks or prepared statement(`?`), if you use both same time that will throw error

Comment: I will check and return to you for thanking) Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answers. I write code here in case someone needs it.
It works this way:

```
app.get('/:name', (req, res, next)=>{
    console.log('Fetching name ' + req.params.name);
    const connection = getConnection();
    const queryStr = `SELECT * FROM products WHERE MATCH(name, url) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) `


    const modelName = req.params.name;

    connection.query( queryStr, modelName, (err, rows, fields)=>{
        console.log(rows);
        if (err){
            res.status(404).send(" Something went wrong");
            // res.sendStatus(500);

            throw err;
        }
        console.log('Ready');
        res.json(rows);


    })
    // res.end();
})
```